# Google VR SDK for Unity v.1.5.0以降で単眼（一眼）モードに変更したい

Tags: unity3d, google-api

子供向けに単眼（一眼）モードでビルドしたいと思っています。

Google VR SDK for Unity v1.40 以前であれば、**GvrViewerMain**のフラグを以下の通り設定することで単眼に変更することが出来ました。

```
VRModeEnabled=false
```

しかし、v1.50以降では、**GvrViewerMain**が、GvrEditorEmulatorに置き換わり、単眼に変更するためのフラグが見当たりません。

どのようにすれば単眼モードでビルド（Android）できるでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

こちらは書籍の内容をもとに色々記載されてますが、何かの参考になれば幸いです・・！
https://github.com/oreilly-japan/unity-virtual-reality-projects-ja